# Navigate listboxitems using arrow Keys

Tags: wpf, navigation, listboxitem, arrow-keys

My usercontrol has Listbox with Images as ListboxItems, here i'm facing an issue when i navigate listbox items (Images) using "Arrow Keys",i could'n navigate the items that is present in Next row, say for example ,List box contains rows of images**(**"I have used WrapPanel"**)**, if i navigate an images using **Right arrow key** i cant able to move to next row,

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
   <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135908/1110311) which almost worked, but not quite.

Put a `KeyDown` event on your ListBox and use its `ItemsCollection` to select the next or previous element when you see a Right or Left keypress.

That moves the selection, but not the keyboard focus (dotted line), so you must also call `MoveFocus` on the element that has Keyboard focus.

```
private void ListBox_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    var list = sender as ListBox;
    switch( e.Key )
    {
        case Key.Right:
            if( !list.Items.MoveCurrentToNext() ) list.Items.MoveCurrentToLast();
            break;

        case Key.Left:
            if( !list.Items.MoveCurrentToPrevious() ) list.Items.MoveCurrentToFirst();
            break;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
    if( list.SelectedItem != null )
    {
        (Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement).MoveFocus( new TraversalRequest( FocusNavigationDirection.Next ) );
    }
}
```

Finally, make sure you have `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on your ListBox.

This will give you the wrap-around behaviour that you want.

Comment: ,thanx for yhe reply,in my project we are handling keydown/keypres..etc with windowsAPI level,which is another Application, so i can't write Keydown event specific to my application, i was looking for , it has to be done in the XAML itself, is it possible to do in XAML file??

Comment: I don't know how you would do it (or if it's possible) solely in XAML.